# Why do multiple conditions in the $match operator fail without an $and operator?

Tags: mongodb

I'm running a `$match` query in an aggregation with multiple conditions. I've tried running the query two ways:

First attempt:

```
db.logs.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: { 
            "message.result": { $type: "object" }, 
            "message.result": { $not: { $type: "array" } },
            "message.result": { $not: { $type: "double" } }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        $project: { 
            aggregatedKeys: { $objectToArray: "$message.result" }
        }
    }
])
```

This fails with the following error:

```
MongoServerError[Location40390]: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $objectToArray requires a document input, found: array
```

Second Attempt:

```
db.logs.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: {
            $and: [
                { "message.result": { $type: "object" } },
                { "message.result": { $not: { $type: "array" } } },
                { "message.result": { $not: { $type: "double" } } }
            ]
        }
    }, 
    { 
        $project: { 
            aggregatedKeys: { $objectToArray: "$message.result" }
        }
    }
])
```

This works as expected.

I've searched [their docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) but I don't understand why the behaviour differs. In `$find` these two queries would be the same. What's different about `$match` that causes the first query to fail?

Comment: I don't think your first query is executable. As key fields must be unique, but there are three duplicate `message.result` keys.

Comment: Okay, so is that the issue do you think? It would be executable if they were different fields?

Comment: Yes, I was just curious that why your 1st query is able to run for the second stage, instead of stopping in the first stage due to the duplicate key errors. You can paste your query into Mongo Playground and see the error.